# Emscripten library make from CMake cannot link

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, emscripten, gdcm

I am using Grassroot Dicom viewer version 2.8.9 to compile into Emscripten library bc on Windows 10 64-bit platform.

I followed the instruction from this [website](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#detecting-emscripten-in-preprocessor)

```
emconfigure cmake .
emmake make VERBOSE=1
```

After that I got library file ending with .a instead of .bc similar to

> libgdcmcharls.a libgdcmCommon.a libgdcmDICT.a ....

when I looked into the assembly code for each static library file it starts with

! arch./

instead of

> BC

as mention in the tutorial [website](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#detecting-emscripten-in-preprocessor) Note

> Some build systems may not properly emit bitcode using the above
>   procedure, and you may see is not valid bitcode warnings. You can run
>   file to check if a file contains bitcode (also you can manually check
>   if the contents start with BC). It is also worth running emmake make
>   VERBOSE=1 which will print out the commands it runs - you should see
>   emcc being used, and not the native system compiler. If emcc is not
>   used, you may need to modify the configure or cmake scripts.

I think this is the problem that I cannot generate libraries with contents start with BC but instead I got ! arch ./ ?

and of course those files cannot be linked from emcc ( cannot find reference error )

```
error: undefined symbol: _ZN4gdcm11ImageReader8GetImageEv
error: undefined symbol: _ZN4gdcm11ImageReaderC1Ev
error: undefined symbol: _ZN4gdcm11ImageReaderD1Ev
error: undefined symbol: _ZN4gdcm5Trace14GetErrorStreamE
```

So I modified GDCM CMakefile.txt according to [this](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/3731)

```
if (EMSCRIPTEN)
    set(CMAKE_AR "emcc" CACHE)
    set(CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".bc")
    set(CMAKE_C_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_AR> -o <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_AR> -o <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
endif()
```

However, it does not help anything. The "make" still generates .a library files

The command that I compiled my code as follows;  I also copy all .a files to the same folder as main.cpp

```
emcc -std=c++17 -O3 -s WASM=1  -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s FULL_ES3=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -o hello.html  -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall', 'cwrap']" --no-heap-copy libgdcmcharls.a libgdcmCommon.a libgdcmDICT.a libgdcmDSED.a libgdcmexpat.a libgdcmIOD.a libgdcmjpeg12.a libgdcmjpeg16.a libgdcmjpeg8.a libgdcmMEXD.a libgdcmMSFF.a libgdcmopenjp2.a libgdcmzlib.a libgdcmuuid.a libsocketxx.a main.cpp ...........
```

The [link](https://ufile.io/ecahv) is my GDCM 2.8.9 library files. Compiled in Windows10 using 
emcmake cmake and finally emmake make ( based on mingw32-make ).

Here is my CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake  after calling emconfigure cmake .

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/workspace/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.14/em++.bat")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1 "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID "Clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION "6.0.1")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION_INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WRAPPER "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_COMPUTED_DEFAULT "98")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES "cxx_std_98;cxx_template_template_parameters;cxx_std_11;cxx_alias_templates;cxx_alignas;cxx_alignof;cxx_attributes;cxx_auto_type;cxx_constexpr;cxx_decltype;cxx_decltype_incomplete_return_types;cxx_default_function_template_args;cxx_defaulted_functions;cxx_defaulted_move_initializers;cxx_delegating_constructors;cxx_deleted_functions;cxx_enum_forward_declarations;cxx_explicit_conversions;cxx_extended_friend_declarations;cxx_extern_templates;cxx_final;cxx_func_identifier;cxx_generalized_initializers;cxx_inheriting_constructors;cxx_inline_namespaces;cxx_lambdas;cxx_local_type_template_args;cxx_long_long_type;cxx_noexcept;cxx_nonstatic_member_init;cxx_nullptr;cxx_override;cxx_range_for;cxx_raw_string_literals;cxx_reference_qualified_functions;cxx_right_angle_brackets;cxx_rvalue_references;cxx_sizeof_member;cxx_static_assert;cxx_strong_enums;cxx_thread_local;cxx_trailing_return_types;cxx_unicode_literals;cxx_uniform_initialization;cxx_unrestricted_unions;cxx_user_literals;cxx_variadic_macros;cxx_variadic_templates;cxx_std_14;cxx_aggregate_default_initializers;cxx_attribute_deprecated;cxx_binary_literals;cxx_contextual_conversions;cxx_decltype_auto;cxx_digit_separators;cxx_generic_lambdas;cxx_lambda_init_captures;cxx_relaxed_constexpr;cxx_return_type_deduction;cxx_variable_templates;cxx_std_17")
set(CMAKE_CXX98_COMPILE_FEATURES "cxx_std_98;cxx_template_template_parameters")
set(CMAKE_CXX11_COMPILE_FEATURES "cxx_std_11;cxx_alias_templates;cxx_alignas;cxx_alignof;cxx_attributes;cxx_auto_type;cxx_constexpr;cxx_decltype;cxx_decltype_incomplete_return_types;cxx_default_function_template_args;cxx_defaulted_functions;cxx_defaulted_move_initializers;cxx_delegating_constructors;cxx_deleted_functions;cxx_enum_forward_declarations;cxx_explicit_conversions;cxx_extended_friend_declarations;cxx_extern_templates;cxx_final;cxx_func_identifier;cxx_generalized_initializers;cxx_inheriting_constructors;cxx_inline_namespaces;cxx_lambdas;cxx_local_type_template_args;cxx_long_long_type;cxx_noexcept;cxx_nonstatic_member_init;cxx_nullptr;cxx_override;cxx_range_for;cxx_raw_string_literals;cxx_reference_qualified_functions;cxx_right_angle_brackets;cxx_rvalue_references;cxx_sizeof_member;cxx_static_assert;cxx_strong_enums;cxx_thread_local;cxx_trailing_return_types;cxx_unicode_literals;cxx_uniform_initialization;cxx_unrestricted_unions;cxx_user_literals;cxx_variadic_macros;cxx_variadic_templates")
set(CMAKE_CXX14_COMPILE_FEATURES "cxx_std_14;cxx_aggregate_default_initializers;cxx_attribute_deprecated;cxx_binary_literals;cxx_contextual_conversions;cxx_decltype_auto;cxx_digit_separators;cxx_generic_lambdas;cxx_lambda_init_captures;cxx_relaxed_constexpr;cxx_return_type_deduction;cxx_variable_templates")
set(CMAKE_CXX17_COMPILE_FEATURES "")
set(CMAKE_CXX20_COMPILE_FEATURES "")

set(CMAKE_CXX_PLATFORM_ID "emscripten")
set(CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_VERSION "")



set(CMAKE_AR "C:/workspace/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.14/emar.bat")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/llvm-ar.exe")
set(CMAKE_RANLIB "C:/workspace/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.14/emranlib.bat")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/llvm-ranlib.exe")
set(CMAKE_LINKER "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/wasm-ld.exe")
set(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX )
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LOADED 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_ABI_COMPILED )
set(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_MINGW )
set(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CYGWIN )
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CYGWIN)
  set(CYGWIN 1)
  set(UNIX 1)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR "CXX")

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_MINGW)
  set(MINGW 1)
endif()
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID_RUN 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS inl;h;hpp;HPP;H;o;O;obj;OBJ;def;DEF;rc;RC)
set(CMAKE_CXX_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS C;M;c++;cc;cpp;cxx;mm;CPP)
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINKER_PREFERENCE 30)
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINKER_PREFERENCE_PROPAGATES 1)

# Save compiler ABI information.
set(CMAKE_CXX_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR "4")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ABI "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE "")

if(CMAKE_CXX_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR)
  set(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P "${CMAKE_CXX_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR}")
endif()

if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ABI)
  set(CMAKE_INTERNAL_PLATFORM_ABI "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ABI}")
endif()

if(CMAKE_CXX_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE)
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE "")
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_CL_SHOWINCLUDES_PREFIX "")
if(CMAKE_CXX_CL_SHOWINCLUDES_PREFIX)
  set(CMAKE_CL_SHOWINCLUDES_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CXX_CL_SHOWINCLUDES_PREFIX}")
endif()





set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_LIBRARIES "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORIES "")
```

Comment: That is a linker error. I don't know anything about the library, nor am I using Windows but are you sure you are linking all the dependencies

Comment: yes. I linked all the libraries file generated from emmake. I test with normal windows. It works fine. but when I used with emcc. it does not work

Comment: @Hemil  Is it possible that errors come from I compile the libraries in different format bc vs normal library code? How could I verify the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. The library that generated from command;

emconfigure cmake .

is not the emcc compatible even when I see the compiler it used em++.bat as the compiler.

How to spot the problem.

I use a program called "Hex Editor Neo" to open the library files ( use only small library files to test, big library files the program crashes).

If it is not compatible to use with emcc. The first few character will be  ! arch This will not work. see the picture below for the library file that is wrong generated from cmake;

[image]

Make sure that you have BC like in the picture below;

[image]

but how to do this

you cannot just use

```
emconfigure cmake .  <---------- wrong
```

you need to put an option to generate bitcode (.bc) by following command

```
emconfigure cmake . -DEMSCRIPTEN_GENERATE_BITCODE_STATIC_LIBRARIES=1
```

Then it will generate all library files ending with .bc and these library files can be linked with emcc